# Cordova Upgrade and jQuery error on ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I had developed an app using cordova v2.4 for android and everything worked fine. I updated to use the latest cordova (v4) and after a bit of hassle with plugins I think I have it back up and running but Im getting an error with an ajax request that previously worked. I have tried everything I can think of but cant figure it out. The problem code is.....

```
var ajx= $.ajax({
  type: (type.toLowerCase()==='post'?'POST':'GET'),
  url: this._prepareUrl(url)+(sid ? '&session='+sid : ''),
  data: data,
  dataType:'html',
  timeout: 60000,
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
  jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
  },
  success: function(html, textStatus, jqXHR){
        //doesnt reach here
  },
  error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log('jqXHR = ' +jqXHR + ' textStatus = ' +textStatus + ' errorThrown = ' +errorThrown);  
         return false;}});
```

The error caught is:

jqXHR = [object Object] textStatus = parsererror errorThrown = Error: jQuery183007247294159606099_1418907848272 was not called

index.html has:

`<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content=""/> 
<script src="cordova.js"></script>`

config.xml has:

`<access origin="" subdomains="true" />`

The code has not changed at all so the upgrade to the latest cordova is the problem. Im missing something small but cant figure out what it is..... If I go back to using the old version of cordova, it works...... same code!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by commenting out the type

```
type: (type.toLowerCase()==='post'?'POST':'GET'),
```

If I add a type, either 'GET' or 'POST' the request fails..... not sure why.....